# Brainfuck interpreter in Clojure

Tags: clojure, interpreter, brainfuck

I'm currently learning Clojure to try to get a good understanding of functionnal programming, so I wrote this brainfuck interpreter that takes a filename on the command line. I tried to make it as correct as I could, but I'm sure there are many things that would make more sense that I didn't think about, or bugs (although it works with the examples on wikipedia). Please criticize!

```
(ns brainfuck.core (:gen-class))

;; Input functions
(def valid-chars '(\< \> \[ \] \. \, \+ \-))

(defn valid-char?
  "Tests whether a character is valid brainfuck. Works with one or
  more characters at a time."
  ([c] (some #{c} valid-chars))
  ([c & others] (every? valid-char? (conj others c))))

(defn filter-invalid
  "Removes characters that aren't valid brainfuck."
  [code]
  (filter valid-char? code))

(defn get-code
  "Returns the sanitized content of file."
  [file]
  (filter-invalid (slurp file)))

(defn get-input
  "Returns one number entered by the user. If the user enters a
  character, it is converted to ASCII. If the user enters a string,
  this function returns 0."
  []
  (let [input (read-line)]
    (if (zero? (count input))
      0
      (int (first input)))))

;; Helper functions
(defn make-context
  "Creates the base context."
  [code-src]
  {:code code-src, :ip 0, :data (vec (repeat 30000 0)), :data-pointer 0})

(defn current-data
  "Returns the current data cell pointed to by :data-pointer."
  [context]
  (nth (context :data) (context :data-pointer)))

(defn current-instruction
  "Returns the current instruction."
  [context]
  (nth (context :code) (context :ip)))

(defn inc-ip
  "Increments the instruction pointer."
  [context]
  (update-in context [:ip] inc))

(defn dec-ip
  "Decrements the instruction pointer."
  [context]
  (update-in context [:ip] dec))

;; Functions to interpret instructions
(defn jump-to-matching-rb
  "Sets instruction pointer to the matching ].
  Should only be called with one argument, the other is for recursion."
  ([context] (jump-to-matching-rb (inc-ip context) 1))
  ([context level]
    (if (= level 0)
      (dec-ip context) ;; we've found the matching bracket
      (cond
        (= (nth (context :code) (context :ip)) \[)
          (jump-to-matching-rb (inc-ip context) (inc level))
        (= (nth (context :code) (context :ip)) \])
          (jump-to-matching-rb (inc-ip context) (dec level))
        :else
          (jump-to-matching-rb (inc-ip context) level)))))

(defn jump-to-matching-lb
  "Sets the instruction pointer to the matching [."
  ([context] (jump-to-matching-lb (dec-ip context) 1))
  ([context level]
    (if (= level 0)
      context ;; we've found the matching bracket
      (cond
        (= (nth (context :code) (context :ip)) \])
          (jump-to-matching-lb (dec-ip context) (inc level))
        (= (nth (context :code) (context :ip)) \[)
          (jump-to-matching-lb (dec-ip context) (dec level))
        :else
          (jump-to-matching-lb (dec-ip context) level)))))

(defn interpret-left-bracket
  "Interprets the [ brainfuck instruction."
  [context]
  (if (= (current-data context) 0)
    (jump-to-matching-rb context)
    context))

(defn interpret-right-bracket
  "Interprets the ] brainfuck instruction."
  [context]
  (jump-to-matching-lb context))

(defn interpret-current
  "Interprets the current instruction and return the modified context.
  For each instruction, the corresponding alteration to the context
  is made and the modified context is returned."
  [context]
  (let [c (current-instruction context)]
    (case c
      \> (update-in context [:data-pointer] inc)
      \< (update-in context [:data-pointer] dec)
      \+ (update-in context [:data (context :data-pointer)] inc)
      \- (update-in context [:data (context :data-pointer)] dec)
      \. (do (print (char (nth (context :data) (context :data-pointer)))) context)
      \, (assoc-in context [:data (context :data-pointer)] (get-input))
      \[ (interpret-left-bracket context)
      \] (interpret-right-bracket context))))

(defn interpret
  "Interprets the brainfuck program."
  [context]
  (loop [ctx context]
    (if (< (ctx :ip) (count (ctx :code)))
      (recur (inc-ip (interpret-current ctx))))))

(defn -main
  "Brainfuck interpreter. Run it with a filename as argument."
  [file]
  (interpret (make-context (get-code file))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need `valid-char?` to accept multiple chars

If write

```
(def valid-char? #{\< \> \[ \] \. \, \+ \-})
```

And if you really need it:

```
(def valid-chars? [& chars]                                                                         
  (every? valid-char? chars))
```

It's more idiomatic to put the keyword for in a map lookup:

```
(defn current-instruction [context]
  (nth (:code context) (:ip context)))
```

Also, it looks like your `jump-to-matching-*` methods should be calling `current-context` rather than doing this same calculation.

It's general using whitespace commas (see make-context) is not considered good style.  It distracts from readability. Normally you'd split each key-value pair on a new line for clarity.

I don't actually know how `[` and `]` work, so this might not be valid, but at first glance I'd want separate out the `find-matching-bracket` from the `jump-to`.  I wonder if the find code can be written in a way to be direction-agnostic so that you only have to write it once?  Maybe not.

The logic in `interpret-current` is really simple but I consider moving each command to a function to make the dispatch really clear.  An (arguable) more elegant approach would be a multimethod:

```
(defmulti interpret-context current-instruction)

(defmethod interpret-context \>
  [context]
  (update-in context [:data-pointer] inc))

(defmethod interpret-context \<
  [context]
  (update-in context [:data-pointer] inc))

;; etc...
```